# How can I update a date property in a MongoDb collection to drop the timezone and make it UTC using a script

Tags: mongodb, date, timezone, updates, utc

I'm looking for a small script to update existing dates in a mongo database and change them to UTC without changing the dates. I had been adding documents into a MongoDb collection with some timeless date properties that, without intending it, included the local timezone. Now that I've caught my mistake, I'm setting their timezone to UTC in the client before being submitted: but, I want to fix the documents I added earlier. Would you provide a sample update script that magically fixes the currents dates I have entered: the properties in UTC should not be affected; the ones with EST or EDT timezones should become UTC dates without changing their dates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing is that Mongo dates *are* UTC, but still there were hours on the dates. To remove the dates, I did this:

```
db.coll.find({$where: "this.dt && this.dt.getUTCHours() > 0"}
).forEach(function(doc) { 
  db.coll.update({ _id : doc._id }, 
   { $set : { dt : new Date(doc.dt.getTime() - 
                  (doc.dt.getUTCHours() * 60 * 60 * 1000))}});}
);
```

And this is a slightly modified copy of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18773804/507421