# split date and update only year in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date

I have to update only year from date field in all the collections.
My collection is as follows.

```
db.test.findOne()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("52e8b96ce4b0e21f470e3851"),
        "requestNumber" : "RN-1007",
        "orderDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00Z"),
        "requiredByDate" : ISODate("2014-01-07T18:30:00Z")
}
```

I tried to get only year field using aggregation.

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$project" : { 'orderDate' : {'$year' : '$orderDate'}}}])
```

**output**: `"orderDate" : 2014`

How do I update only year from 2014 to 2015 without changing the month, date and time stamp?

Comment: Please visit this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759375/how-does-one-properly-increment-many-dates-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[`$add`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#add-aggregation)** arithmetic operator in your **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline. The following aggregation operation uses the **[`$add`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#add-aggregation)** expression to create an additional field the `orderDateYearOlder` that updates the year part by adding `365*24*60*60000` milliseconds (i.e. 365 days) to the `orderDate` field :

```
db.test.aggregate([
     { 
         "$project": { 
             "requestNumber": 1,              
             "requiredByDate" : 1,
             "orderDate" : 1,
             "orderDateYearOlder": { "$add": [ "$orderDate", 365*24*60*60000 ] } 
        } 
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("52e8b96ce4b0e21f470e3851"),
            "requestNumber" : "RN-1007",
            "orderDate" : ISODate("2014-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "orderDateYearOlder" : ISODate("2015-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
            "requiredByDate" : ISODate("2014-01-07T18:30:00.000Z")            
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Another way would be using the **[Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** operations to update the date field in the collection as follows:

```
var bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    count = 0;

db.test.find({"orderDate": { "$exists": true, "$type": 9 }}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var newOrderDate = new Date(doc.orderDate.getTime() + (365*24*60*60000));
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "orderDate": newOrderDate }
    });
    count++;
    if (count % 100 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.test.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (count % 100 != 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```