# Mongoose increment dates in 'x' days from previous value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime

I have a `sprint` schema, which has starting and ending dates.

I want that when an end date is actualize, increase or decrease the days of all others are followed.

I want to do this in a one query.

I found this:

```
var start = new Date(2010, 11, 1);
var end = new Date(2010, 11, 30);

db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

`$gte: start` selects the documents where the value of the field is greater than or equal to (i.e. >=) a specified value.

It works inside the update query, but I don't know how to increase dates in `x` days.

The format of dates in mongoDB is like this:

`ISODate("2016-06-03T14:09:25.330Z")`.

My `var start` is a variable like ISODate variable.

Thank you very much.

Comment: hmm, are you going to update value, or just change search criteria?

Comment: I want to update value

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759375/how-does-one-properly-increment-many-dates-in-mongodb)

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks good idea. I'll prove it. ;D