# How do I update the existing date without updating the time in updateMany query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema called Ride which has a depTime field which contains the ride date and time.

```
ride: new Schema({
 ...
 ...
 depTime: Date,
})
```

I am running a cronjob which first finds all the rides that have completed. Now, I want to run an updateMany operation which updates only the date to the next day without changing the time of all the completed rides. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Would be useful if you also show how you currently do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one properly increment many dates in mongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759375/how-does-one-properly-increment-many-dates-in-mongodb)

Comment: @Zlatko The query given in the example is first finding all the documents and then updating it one by one. Is it not possible to do it using the updateMany query?