# MongoDB: how to pass current value to operator?

Tags: mongodb

Here is sample db structure where I'm trying to modify value of every `work_starts_at`.

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "work_week": [
        {'name': 'ponedeljak', 'work_hours': []},
        {'name': 'utorak', 'work_hours': []},
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "work_week": [
        {'name': 'monday', 'work_hours': [
            {'work_starts_at': 1, 'work_ends_at': 2}
        ]},
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "work_week": [
        {'name': 'понедельник', 'work_hours': [
            {'work_starts_at': 2, 'work_ends_at': 3},
            {'work_starts_at': 6, 'work_ends_at': 7},
        ]},
        {'name': 'вторник', 'work_hours': []},
    ]
}
```

The best solution I came to is the following (in python), but instead of subtracting `5` from current value of `work_week.work_hours.work_starts_at` it's traversing I got `null`. I suppose it's because construction `$$CURRENT.work_hours.work_starts_at` doesn't point to `work_starts_at`, so I'm actually subtracting `5` from `null`.

How can I properly address value of currently traversed element?

```py
collection.update_many(
{},
[
    {
        '$set': {
            'work_week.work_hours.work_starts_at': {
                '$subtract': ['$$CURRENT.work_hours.work_starts_at', 5]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way from the mongo shell (it must be very similar in python):

```
db.collection.update({
 "work_week.work_hours.work_starts_at": {
  $exists: true
}
},
{
 $inc: {
   "work_week.$[].work_hours.$[].work_starts_at": -5
}
},
{
 multi: true
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jql_otJR-BB)

Comment: Suddenly ran into painful thing... I have to modify date. `$inc` doesn't work with dates. How to do it in mongodb then?

Comment: for dates you will need to use $set  , check the answers in this ticket for latest mongo versions there improved options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759375/how-does-one-properly-increment-many-dates-in-mongodb

Comment: Already did it, thanks! I've managed to change dates in another collection, where data were flat (kinda like `{_id: 1, date_to_change: ...}`). But still can't figure out how to change date in array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @R2D2! I've translated it to Python (pymongo):

```py
collection.update_many(
        {'work_week.work_hours.work_starts_at': {'$exists': True}},
        {'$inc': {
            'work_week.$[].work_hours.$[].work_starts_at': -5
        }}
    )
```